# Accessing 1D Touch music-streaming platform with Rhythmbox

Tags: music, rhythmbox, streaming

I got a account on [1D Touch](http://music.1dtouch.com), a streaming platform, and it will be nice if I could have an access with Rhythmbox (instead of my web browser).
The platform is sending mp3, readable with an API using oauth (nothing else...).

Can someone tell me, please, how to listen to my favorite platform using Rhythmbox ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to listen to music from 1D Touch ... there is a big but though.

Rhythmbox has the ability to add extra software to it called "plugins".  These can be written in Python or C/C++.

Plugins give extra capabilities that Rhythmbox lacks natively.

You'll need to [create a plugin](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Rhythmbox/Plugins/WritingGuide) yourself - or encourage some kindly soul to create one for you.

There is API documentation for 1D [here](https://gist.github.com/kevcha/afe6d905569a705e921e) to help.

Given the nature of the plugin, I would suggest looking at the [SoundCloud plugin](https://github.com/GNOME/rhythmbox/tree/master/plugins/soundcloud) available in Rhythmbox 3.2 and later.  You can take that as a basis and substitute the SoundCloud API calls with that of 1D.

Having had a quick scout around, there are no Linux based media players that have 1D support built in.

Happy writing!

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look at the SoundCloud plugin and try to work with 1D dev team.